# jquery ui tabs change selected tab text

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs

the following doesn't work:

```
$("#tabs").tabs( "option", "selected" ).text('Logout');
```

neither is

```
$("#tabs").tabs( "option", "selected" ).text()='Logout';
```

with error:

```
$("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected").text is not a function
```

how do i change text of a tab please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are using returns an integer value for the selected tab.  Its not an object that has a `text()` method on it.  You will have to do something like this:

```
var selectedTab = $("#tabs").tabs( "option", "selected" );
$("#tabs ul li a").eq(selectedTab).text("your text");
```

Documentation here - http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-selected

Sample code here - http://jsbin.com/ohogey/edit#javascript,html

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the `select` event on the jQuery Tabs element.  Inside the function just find your DOM element and change the innerText value.

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
   select: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

Comment: see @hope_is_grim answer below, the value you are getting back is an integer, not a DOM element in the page, therefore there is no text() property on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected")
```

return the selected tabs ID.
If you want to change the caption of the tab when it is selected,
you can do it like this

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
  select: function(e, ui) {
    $(ui.tab).text('someText');
  }
});
```

Comment: oh i see now =)) the problem i got now is that it changes name to "Logout" of _every_ tab i click on, despite login script only ran once!